# How to install the MeshroomMaya plugin for Maya in Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, cmake, maya, meshroom

I'm trying to install the plugin [MeshroomMaya](https://github.com/alicevision/MeshroomMaya) to my Maya 2020 in Windows 10.

I have git and CMake installed. I've installed qt5 through vcpkg as well and I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with the v142 build tools.

Anyways, when you look at the *Installation* section for the plugin in GitHub you can see that it's very short. I assume that `$MAYA_BIN` has to point to the maya bin folder. I guess `$MAYA_QMAKE_PATH` has to point to the maya bin folder as well because there is the only qmake file I can find in the whole Maya directory. Now I'm not sure where `$INSTALL_DIRECTORY` has to point at ...

The biggest point I'm struggeling with is that all those commands are bash commands. The *configure* file is a bash script and now I'm thinking that this whole plugin is for Linux only. Right? I've seen some tools for Windows like [that](https://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/) but I'm not sure if that is the right thing for me for installing the Maya plugin? Will the Shell handle the Windows installation of Maya as it would handle the Linux one? Is it even meant to be used for tasks like that? (Running bash commands in Windows' filesystem?)

I'm sorry for the vague question but I'm not that experienced with deployment in general. I thought about translating the scripts to PowerShell commands but have a feeling I would put way to much time into that for no real reason ...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `$INSTALL_DIRECTORY` is your choice. It is typically wherever *you* want the package to be installed...

Comment: @squareskittles Thanks! I was confused because it is assigned to a variable in the configuration like so: ```-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_DIRECTORY```, and thought there is more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cmake build setup is available, I usually use cmake for windows and setup the cmake via cmake-gui.exe. There you can set all needed variables and point to the correct location. The configure scripts only call cmake as much as I can see. From the cmake-gui you set the visual studio version and it will create a VS solution for you. Concerning qt, I suppose you should use the Maya specific version of qt, but I'm not sure where you can get them.

Comment: That's not the full answer but it gave me the hints I needed to find out things myself. Dankeschön. :)